CSS backdrop-filter showing a darken area at start of div
I am trying to create a glassmorphic style header. On big screen it works without any issue, but on mobile screen it shows a darken area at start of div.
One thing that I noticed is that after a certain width it starts to appear. Like below 420px.
This is the picture on Desktop

This is the picture on Mobile]

This is the React code. And below are the styles.
import React from "react";
import * as styles from "./Header.module.css";
import { Link as GatsbyLink } from "gatsby";

enum Routes {
  HOME_PAGE = '/',
  WORK = 'work',
  ABOUT = 'about'
}

const Header = () => {

  return (
    <header >
      <div>
        <nav className={styles.glassMorphism}>
          <ul>
            <li className={window.location.pathname === Routes.HOME_PAGE ? styles.active : ''}>
              <GatsbyLink to={Routes.HOME_PAGE}>Home</GatsbyLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <GatsbyLink to={Routes.WORK}>Work</GatsbyLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <GatsbyLink to={Routes.ABOUT}>About</GatsbyLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;

Using the following styles
.glassMorphism {
  background-color: rgb(17 25 40 / 31%);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(50%);
  /* -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 20px ); */
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

header {
  width: 98vw;
  /* padding-left: 10px; */
}

header>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav a {
  color: aliceblue;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

ul {
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(91 91 91 / 13%);
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 9px;
}

This is the HTML from Browser.
<header>
  <div bis_skin_checked="1">
    <nav class="Header-module--glassMorphism--f467d">
      <ul>
        <li class="Header-module--active--29e1b">
          <a aria-current="page" class="" href="/">Home</a
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/work/" bis_skin_checked="1">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/about/" bis_skin_checked="1">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

Update
I find that nested backdrop-filter are causing issue. Removing any of the backdrop filter removes the darken area. Is there other way to use nested backdrop-filters?

CAn you go into your browsers devtools inspect facility to find the exact HTML and CSS that is being applied and put it into your question (not as an image, copy the text and add it).

@AHaworth I searched on the issue and it looks like that nested backdrop filter is causing this behavior. I have added the HTML.
